# adding element to array iterated over in foreach statement in php

Tags: php, arrays

In the following I will try to explain precisely how iteration works in the different cases.
I wonder
why

```
$arr=[1,2,3];
    $count=0;
    foreach ($arr as $value){ \\
        echo "$value\n";
        if ($count++<10) $arr[]=$value+1; \\add new element
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

results in

```
1
2
3
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
)
```

while

```
    $arr=[1,2,3];
    $count=0;
    foreach ($arr as &$value){ \\reference elemnt
        echo "$value\n";
        if ($count++<10) $arr[]=$value+1;
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

results in

```
1
2
3
2
3
4
3
4
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
```

)

or better  question what is foreach mechanism in php
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration you will get array with the previous added element if you use refference. you can do following to see how it works:

```
$arr=[1,2,3];
$count=0;
foreach ($arr as &$value){
    if ($count++<10) $arr[]=$value+1;
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically when iterating through an array by value PHP takes a copy of the array to iterate over so it will only do 3 loops. If you iterate by reference then it iterates over the array itself meaning that changes you make are reflected on the loop.

Your code shows this well, but also consider [this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8efbb39f8fd291bb2ae943305d2bfe5f89bfff07)

```
<?php 
$arr=[1,2,3];
$count=0;
foreach ($arr as $index => $value){ //
    if (isset($arr[$index+1])) {
        $arr[$index+1]++;
    }
    echo "$value\n";
}
print_r($arr);
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

When you change it to:

```
 <?php 
$arr=[1,2,3];
$count=0;
foreach ($arr as $index => &$value){ //
    if (isset($arr[$index+1])) {
        $arr[$index+1]++;
    }
    echo "$value\n";
}
print_r($arr);
```

The changes are instantly reflected on the loop,i.e., it prints:

```
1
3
4
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

Comment: could any one tell me what's run under hood about these codes,please.

Comment: @Bagheri PHP is open source and written in C. If you think you can handle that then you can [check out the source](https://github.com/php/php-src). I can't help you with that.